# PHP E_ERROR on preg_replace: regexp code has no debug info

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out why an E_ERROR is logged when running through the script using a debugger - since it does not appear in my errorlog when the script runs normally, I would assume that it is debugger-generated.
This is the E_ERROR:

```
source.php(1594) : regexp code  File /path/to/file(1594) : regexp code has no debug-info. Debugging is not possible.    E_ERROR
```

These are lines 1593 and 1594:

```
$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',
          "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
```

Thanks for any suggestions - I suppose for the moment I can leave this unattended to, but was trying to make sure.

Comment: F^up: I have just realised that the debugger does not appear to complain about preg_replace not returning debug info - I think it is complaining about not being able to evaluate the "ev[a|i]l" code to be run with the /e flag during runtime. I'll check that - might also be interesting if that applies to eval in general.

Comment: The `e` modifier is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) as of **PHP 5.5.0**, you should use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks Hamza, that's useful to know. The E_ERROR wasn't a deprecated, though - it is now relatively clear that it was generated by the debugger's inability to generate information about the eval'ed code. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback()

```
$out = preg_replace_callback(
  '((?P<char>[\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377]))',
  function ($match) {
    return sprintf('=%02X', ord($match['char']));
  },
  $in
);
```

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but it looks pretty similar to what I have in my code today. I'll accept that as an answer.